# Grouping ManyToMany values in template/formset

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a content-analysis application in which comments are tagged.  Each of the tags has a "connotation."  Because the multiple tags can apply to multiple comments, I've set up a many-to-many relationship between the Tags models and the Comments model.  The Tags model has a field for the connotation.  I have a working formset with the exception of this usability feature.

### From models.py

```
class Tags( models.Model ):

    CONNOTATION_CHOICES = ( ( '+', 'Positive' ), ( '-', 'Negative' ), ( '?', 'Ambivalent' ), ( '=', 'Informational' ), )

    tag = models.CharField( max_length = 40, blank = False )
    description = models.TextField( blank = True )
    connotation = models.CharField( max_length = 1, choices = CONNOTATION_CHOICES, blank = False )

    def __str__( self ):
        return "".join(( self.connotation, self.tag ))


class Comments( models.Model ):

    comment     = models.TextField( blank = False )
    tags        = models.ManyToManyField( Tags )
    coder       = models.ForeignKey( User, null = True, blank = True )
    coder_comment = models.TextField( blank = True )

    def __str__( self ):
        return "{0} [{1}]".format( self.comment[:40], self.coder )
```

### From forms.py

```
class CommentForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = [ 
                'tags',
                'comment',
                'coder',
                'coder_comment',
                ]
        widgets = {
                'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                }
```

### From views.py

```
def edit( request ):
    FormSet = modelformset_factory( Comments, form=CommentForm, extra=0 )

    # Form not submitted, need to generate a blank one
    if request.method != 'POST':
        query = Comments.objects.all()

        group_by = 25
        paginator = Paginator( query, group_by )

        try:
            page = request.GET.get( 'page' )
            comments = paginator.page( page )
        except ( PageNotAnInteger, KeyError ):
            comments = paginator.page( 1 )
        except EmptyPage:
            comments = paginator.page( paginator.num_pages )

        page_query = query.filter( id__in = [ comment.id for comment in comments ] )
        formset = FormSet( queryset = page_query )

        context = { 'comments': comments, 'formset': formset }
        return render( request, 'commoncore/edit.html', context )

    # Submitted, so validate and process data
    else:
        # . . .
```

My question:  In the template, I'd like to group the tags by connotation.  Something like

```
{% for form in formset %}
    <td>
    {% for t in form.tags %}
        {% if t.connotation == "+" %}{{ t.tag }}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
    <td>
    {% for t in form.tags %}
        {% if t.connotation == "-" %}{{ t.tag }}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
    <td>
    {% for t in form.tags %}
        {% if t.connotation == "?" %}{{ t.tag }}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
    <td>
    {% for t in form.tags %}
        {% if t.connotation == "=" %}{{ t.tag }}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

But this does not work because `t` apparently does not actually have access to `Tag`'s fields --- or at least I cannot discover where they are hidden.  Is it necessary to provide multiple tag lists filtered in `views.py`?  Or, I could write a template filter based on the `__str__()` representation of the Tags, but that seems a bit clunky.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Post your view code.

Comment: What's formset look like and what does each element in the formset look like? Like @Othman suggested, you have to show the code for the function that handles this view. Also, I don't see the **many-to-many** relationship in your Tags' model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying `regoup` and `curry` and various other methods without success, I wound up using the following hard-coded approach, rather than a desired `foreach`-like approach.  In `forms.py`:

```
class CommentCodesForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    pos_tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset = Tags.objects.all().filter( connotation = '+' ),
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            )
    neg_tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset = Tags.objects.all().filter( connotation = '-' ),
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            )
    amb_tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset = Tags.objects.all().filter( connotation = '?' ),                                                    
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            )
    info_tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset = Tags.objects.all().filter( connotation = '=' ),
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            )

    class Meta:
        model = CommentCodes
        fields = [
                'pos_tags',
                'neg_tags',
                'amb_tags',
                'info_tags',
...
```

and in the template I used normal `{{ pos_tags }}` notation.